# Python Regex and HTML

Tags: python, regex

First I am painfully aware that parsing HTML with regex is not "good form". However, I am dealing with poorly formed HTML that does not validate when parsed with such tools as lxml.

My goal is to select only the **span** elements that contain a **br** element. Below is my attempt:

Setup the sample input

```
import re
xx= '<div> <span>123</span> <span>456 <br> 789</span>  </div>'
```

This identifies the two spans properly but only when the **?** is present.I don't understand why this is the case.

```
re.findall('<span>.*?</span>', xx)
['<span>123</span>', '<span>456 <br> 789</span>']
```

I would have thought this would have only selected the span with the br tag present but instead, it selects the start span tag from the first span and the end span tag from the last span making only one entry selected.

```
re.findall('<span>.*?<br>.*?</span>', xx)
['<span>123</span> <span>456 <br> 789</span>']
```

Please explain why I am seeing this behavior.

Comment: Use a parser: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @ctwheels that was my first thought to, but OP said a parser doesn't work because the text does not validate.

Comment: There are parsers that can work with invalid markup. Where `lxml` may have failed, another parser may be adequate for the case. Especially given what is being extracted (at least in the given example) IS valid markup.

Comment: Use beautifulsoup

Comment: @MK. - I just found that package. I am going to try it.  Hope it works.

Comment: @pault It's just a matter of seeing numbers at left side of a comment

Comment: @Alex oh it will.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your other requirements, you could do something like

```
re.findall('<span>[^<]*<br>.*?</span>', xx)
```

to match only the span with a `<br>`, But in general, use some parser as the comments suggest.